# VS in tutorial behaves differently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've been watching this tutorial http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=296114. At the very begining empty Windows forms project is created in VS. When I create empty Windows forms project I have there files: `Form1`, `Program.cs`. When the guy from the tutorial creates it he has `Form1` and `App.config` files.

Why is that ? Can I Make my project run the GUI without having Main method (like in WPF but with Winforms) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there will always be a `Main` method really. It's just that in VB projects I believe it's autogenerated and not even shown. There's no equivalent option in C#.

Comment: Thank you, great. What about my "subquestion"? Is there any way to replace `Main` method by some declaration of "window that schould be run on application start"? Something like `App.xaml` in WPF ?

Comment: @drasto: Program.cs can be used the same way: just change `            Application.Run(new Form1());` to some other form.

Comment: I know. I just don't like having there `Program.cs`. I preferer declarative way... Write what schould be run instead of how to run something...

Comment: @drasto: For WPF IIRC, the Main method is generated as part of App.g.cs or whatever the main App file is called. Have a look at the generated source to see. There's no equivalent for WinForms.